# Parsing date in a Facebook application using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, date, wamp

i'm trying a simple facebook application, running on localhost using wamp 2.0 , i got the date using the following code as shown here, when i run echo($bd); i get the correct result but when the following code runs i get an error.

Code

```
$bd = $fbme['birthday'];
    $datearr = "0";$month = "0"; $date = "0"; $year = "0";
    $datearr = explode('-', $bd);
    list($month,$date,$year) = $datearr;
    echo($month);
```

Error :

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp......\index.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp.....\index.php on line 30

Could you please suggest the reason and why this is occuring, any way how to get rid of this. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string stored in `$fbme['birthday']` does not contain any '-' chars. Most likely it is empty. Check where `$fbme` is populated and an actual birthday is present.

Comment: @gamebit07: if the format is like what you are saying, then why you are exploding the **wrong** character?!